# Setting custom attributes in AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using google as federated identity in aws cognito.

I have got the user created but I am not able to add the custom attributes, I have in the user pool. I am trying to add custom attributes using the console.

I don't see this custom attribute when I click on `User and Groups` -> Any of the user.

I also tried using the cognito pool as Idp ( alongwith Google ) but that also didn't change anything.

I have also tried creating user using this :

```
aws cognito-idp admin-create-user \
    --profile stage \
    --region ap-south-1 \
    --user-pool-id SSO-Test-User-Pool \
    --username test@test.com \
    --user-attributes Name=email,Value=test@test.com Name=custom:custom:role,Value="cms.tv_admin" \
    --message-action SUPPRESS
```

But it gives error :

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the AdminCreateUser operation: 1 validation error detected: Value 'SSO-Test-User-Pool' at 'userPoolId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\w-]+_[0-9a-zA-Z]+
```

and same goes while I tried updating attributes using this :

```
aws cognito-idp admin-update-user-attributes \
    --profile stage \
    --region ap-south-1 \
    --user-pool-id SSO-Test-User-Pool \
    --username Google_113423776936123400493 \
    --user-attributes Name=custom:custom:role,Value=admin
```

Further I found that these commands can be run using the app and that they need to have the code returned after logging in, which they would get using the redirect URI, I suppose.

How do I use that from the CLI ?

I have the readable and writable attributes set on the custom property by the app in the `App Client Settings`.

Thanks.

Let me know if more info is required.

[custom attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CSz3.png)

[User Property Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbiUQ.png)

[app client settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIQRO.png)

[app client settings - readable/writable permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mEKV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your federated pool name, not the federated pool id.

You can get your federated pool id via the following methods:

From the console select your identity pool, at the top of the page above `Pool ARN` will be `Pool Id`. It will be prefixed with the region in which the pool is created.

Alternatively run the [list-identity-pools](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-identity/list-identity-pools.html), then copy the value from the `Id` attribute.